# How is it possible that go routines interleave perfectly?

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm surprised that go routines seem to interleave perfectly... After seeing this, I am starting to believe there's some missing information about the internals that I haven't learned about yet. Example:

```
$ go run x.go > output
$ grep ping output | wc -l
404778
$ grep pong output | wc -l
404777
$ cat x.go 
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Ball struct{ hits int }

func main() {
    table := make(chan *Ball)
    go player("ping", table)
    go player("pong", table)

    table <- new(Ball) // game on; toss the ball
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    <-table // game over; grab the ball
}

func player(name string, table chan *Ball) {
    for {
        ball := <-table
        ball.hits++
        fmt.Println(name, ball.hits)
        //time.Sleep(1 * time.Millisecond)
        table <- ball
    }
}
```

However long you set the timeout in the player function (or remove it all together) you always get #ping == #ping +/- 1.

Comment: You should accept @Dave C's answer.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

By default [GOMAXPROCS](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GOMAXPROCS) is set to 1 and as a result you see this behaviour. If you increase GOMAXPROCS it will no longer be deterministic.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057210/does-the-goroutines-created-in-the-same-goroutines-execute-always-in-order) for an example

EDIT @DaveC disagrees however a simple test shows otherwise. The channels are synchonised yes, however the order of the goroutines executing is not. These are different concepts. Type in the above code, set GOMAXPROCS > 1 and run ...

```
➜  tmp  export GOMAXPROCS=2
➜  tmp  go run balls.go
ping 1
pong 2
➜  tmp  go run balls.go
pong 1
ping 2
➜  tmp
```

As you can see above the goroutines order of execution is not deterministic

Comment: Incorrect, re-read the code. The un-buffered channels are synchronized no matter how many threads are allowed.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for... Whether it actually applies in the case of this specific code problem is currently unclear to me. I would expect that ping *could* get called right after ping, thus skipping a pong, but perhaps I am new to golang and thus possibly missing some undocumented nuance of the language.

Comment: @DaveC edited with example output. I understand that the channels will always go from ping to pong (or vice versa) and never pong to pong or ping to ping due to the channel synchronisation.

Comment: @LenW it's not so much the point which goroutine starts (ping or pong). The question is, why does a ping always follow a pong and never another ping. The correct answer has nothing to do with GOMAXPROCS. It is (as @Dave C correctly writes) the effect that `<-` blocks until someone reads from the channel. Thus when pong blocks, ping is the only running goroutine left that can read from the channel.

Comment: @topskip, exactly. The OP is only doing a grep count on the output and noticing that the pattern is always … ping, pong, ping, pong, … (without regard to if the first one is ping or pong) and the OP talks of interleaving. This has nothing what-so-ever to do with which starts first and how/when main will "interfere" to stop the game.

Comment: @topskip completely understood as above

Comment: I agree with your observation that the output is nondeterministic (since it may start with a ping or a pong), but the question asks about "perfect interleaving" of the pings and pongs. So I think this answer doesn't answer the question in a useful way, even though what it says is technically correct.

Comment: I think your statement "order of execution is not deterministic" is misleading because it implies way too much. The output is *perfectly* deterministic except for one thing: the choice of the first player. The OP was asking why every ping has a pong, and that has nothing to do with `GOMAXPROCS`.

Answer (score 7):

You're using a un-buffered channel and your two goroutines synchronize with it. With an un-buffered channel the channel write (`table <- ball`) can only complete once someone somewhere has done a read (`<-table`) so a single goroutine can never read the value it's writing. That's the whole point of this example.

Comment: Put another way, the "missing information" the question refers to is that unbuffered channel sends are *synchronous*: the sending goroutine goes to sleep until the other receives the value. If you want to look into how this happens, look for info on the goroutine scheduler (which is like the scheduler that governs threads in your operating system).

Comment: Put another way, you've discovered one of the great features of using Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP) that underpins the Go model: what you see is what you get in terms of "this happens" then "that happens". This becomes especially useful when external i/o is involved - you don't have to write chains of callbacks. Just block; it's OK.

Comment: Where in the code does it say that you can't have ping call right after ping finished? Is it *impossible* ?

Comment: The behaviour of unbuffered channels has been mentioned several times here. It's impossible since `table <- ball` does not return until *after* `ball := <- table` returns in the other go routine. By the time the first goroutine gets back through the for loop and tries to read again it has to wait for another, different channel send.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog](http://divan.github.io/posts/go_concurrency_visualize/):

Goroutines would interleave perfectly for any number of players:

> The answer is because Go runtime holds waiting [FIFO queue for receivers](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/chan.go#L34) (goroutines ready to receive on the particular channel), and
>   in our case every player gets ready just after he passed the ball on
>   the table