# Ordering of senders in a Go channel

Tags: concurrency, go, channel

Consider the ping pong example from http://www.golang-book.com/10/index.htm#section2.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func pinger(c chan string) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        c <- "ping"
    }
}

func ponger(c chan string) {
    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        c <- "pong"
    }
}

func printer(c chan string) {
    for {
        msg := <- c
        fmt.Println(msg)
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1)
    }
}

func main() {
    var c chan string = make(chan string)

    go pinger(c)
    go ponger(c)
    go printer(c)

    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

The authors write:

> "The program will now take turns printing ping and pong."

However, for this to be true, Go must decide on an order in which senders can send into a channel? Otherwise, there would be no guarantee that a ping would be sent before a pong (i.e. you can't get two pings, or two pongs in a row). How does this work?

Comment: My gut feeling is that the order is just by coincidence. But I guess peterSO will prove me wrong.

Comment: Correct. This is a poor example of using channels, and doesn't even ping-pong (usually meaning a call+response) in any way.

Comment: It's not a coincidence, it's a side effect of the fact that very little happens besides the sending, and that printing takes longer than sending. when one sender sends and the channel clears, the other one is already ready with their own send, etc. It's a really bad example of channels as a sync mechanism, and if any of them was doing real work it wouldn't be that way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no synchronization between the `ping` and `pong` goroutines, therefore there is no guarantee that the responses will print in order.

If you force the goroutines to race with GOMAXPROCS>1, you get random output:

```
pong
ping
ping
pong
ping
pong
ping
pong
pong
```

This isn't even an example of a "ping-pong", since there's is no call and response.

Answer (score 1):

There was a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29057210/does-the-goroutines-created-in-the-same-goroutines-execute-always-in-order/29060433#29060433) on the order of selection of messages entering a channel recently.

The answer is that the order is **normally non-deterministic**. This is intentional.